# Tricky column repleacement from one file to another

Tags: bash, sed, awk

here is the problem, there are two files:

**aaa.txt**:

```
1       abc
2       def  
3       ghi  
4       jkl  
5       xyz
```

**bbb.txt**

```
4       9  
3       2  
3       3  
4       9  
5       8  
2       6  
1       7
```

The question is how to replace first column of file bbb.txt with the corresponding strings from second column of aaa.txt ? 
Output should look like this:

**bbb.txt:**

```
jkl       9  
ghi       2  
ghi       3  
jkl       9  
xyz       8  
def       6  
abc       7
```

What I come up with already is very slow multiple grep use:

```
cat bbb.txt | awk '{print $1}' | while read k; 
do res=$(grep $k aaa.txt | awk '{print $2}'); 
echo $res >> out
done
```

But it does not do the job at all and i have this suspicion that its way easier to do..

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Bash:

```
dict=()
while read key value; do
  dict[$key]=$value
done < aaa.txt

while read key text; do
  echo "${dict[$key]} $text"
done < bbb.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

quick and dirty:

```
kent$  awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next;}$1=a[$1]' aaa.txt bbb.txt 
jkl 9
ghi 2
ghi 3
jkl 9
xyz 8
def 6
abc 7
```

Comment: Very good, but it kill tabulators, file bbb.txt is tab-delimited and has multiple columns..

Comment: @user1302717 still quick&dirty: pipe the output the awk line to "column -t". so it looks like: awk.....|column -t

Comment: Thanks so much ;] You R the boss;}

Comment: Don't need 'column': set the awk OFS variable: `awk -v OFS="\t" '...'`

Comment: @glennjackman you are right, but that needs edit the answer, not dirty as a pipe. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:(GNU sed?)

```
sed 's/^\(\S*\)\s*\(\S*\).*/s|^\1\\>|\2|/' aaa.txt | sed -i -f - bbb.txt
```

In essence, convert the `aaa.txt` into a `sed` script which looks like so:

```
sed 's/^\(\S*\)\s*\(\S*\).*/s|^\1\\>|\2|/' aaa.txt                   
s|^1\>|abc|
s|^2\>|def|
s|^3\>|ghi|
s|^4\>|jkl|
s|^5\>|xyz|
```

Then pipe this through to a second `sed` program that runs these instructions against `bbb.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Is order important? If not how about

```
join -t $'\t' <(sort -n aaa.txt) <(sort -n bbb.txt) | cut -d$'\t' -f2-
```